# Intent to launch marketplace app, show all apps by publisher?

Tags: android

Is there a way to get the marketplace app to open to a page showing all your apps? I was hoping this would have done it:

```
 https://market.android.com/developer?pub=My+Company+Name
```

but it doesn't. Basic idea is to have a button in my game to take users to a page of other apps I've written.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search?q=pub:My%20Company%20Name")));`

Comment: Ok thanks - it's weird to me that they don't provide a direct hook, if we're in the situation where we know the exact company we want to show.